# ld.so.preload and login

Tags: linux, authentication, ld

I added library to ld.so.preload and path to ld.so.conf.d
When I run a binary or run ldd on binary everything seems to work. Problem appears when I try to login: After putting user, but before password, I get error that library cannot be found and won't be preloaded. Additionally after putting password (correct one) I get 'Authentication failure' error.
Strace showed that login does read ld.so.preload, but doesn't read ld.so.cache.
Standard folders are being searched for library, but not those from ld.so.cache. Is this a bug or a feature? It would mean that I have to copy libraries to 'standard folders'? Or is there a way to workaround it?

Regards

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Issue was caused by selinux. Changing policy fixed it.

Comment: Or not... Problem still open (I made mistake during validation).
selinux is blocking login when ld.so.preload file is not empty. Any ideas?